# Expand +/- button for taxonomy display in a page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've a taxonomy with years as its terms. It has some content within each terms. Now, I want to display the terms in a list like structure with a `+` as its suffix. So, when a user clicks the `+` button, the content within the terms will be displayed as expanded.

The taxonomy term list should appear as below
[image]

I'm using Drupal-7, tried to install `Advanced book block module`, but it works with drupal-6.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to try to use [Views Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion):

[image]

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the Views module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery accordion, using
>   the first field as the header for the accordion rows.
>
> For Drupal 7 the module integrates the jQuery UI Accordion plugin as a
>   views style plugin. You can configure the options provided by the
>   jQuery UI plugin.
>
> For Drupal 6 the module used it's own jQuery code, so a different set
>   of features is available for D6.

Views can override the default taxonomy pages, or you can try to create your own grouped taxonomy listing which uses this display plugin.